# automatic wrapper that adds an output to a function

Tags: python, function, wrapper, output

[I am using python 2.7]

I wanted to make a little wrapper function that add one output to a function. Something like:

```
def add_output(fct, value):
    return lambda *args, **kargs: (fct(*args,**kargs),value)
```

Example of use:

```
def f(a): return a+1
g = add_output(f,42)
print g(12)            # print: (13,42)
```

This is the expected results, but it does not work if the function given to `add_ouput` return more than one output (nor if it returns no output). In this case, the wrapped function will return two outputs, one contains all the output of the initial function (or `None` if it returns no output), and one with the added output:

```
def f1(a): return a,a+1
def f2(a): pass
g1 = add_output(f1,42)
g2 = add_output(f2,42)
print g1(12)            # print: ((12,13),42)   instead of (12,13,42)
print g2(12)            # print: (None,42)      instead of 42
```

I can see this is related to the impossibility to distinguish between one output of type tuple and several output. But this is disappointing not to be able to do something so simple with a dynamic language like python...

Does anyone have an idea on a way to achieve this automatically and *nicely enough*, or am I in a dead-end ?

Note:
In case this change anything, my real purpose is doing some wrapping of class (instance) method, to looks like function (for workflow stuff). However it is require to add `self` in the output (in case its content is changed):

```
class C(object):
    def f(self): return 'foo','bar'

def wrap(method):
    return lambda self, *args, **kargs: (self,method(self,*args,**kargs))

f = wrap(C.f)
c = C()
f(c)          # returns (c,('foo','bar')) instead of (c,'foo','bar')
```

I am working with python 2.7, so I a want solution with this version or else I abandon the idea. I am still interested (and maybe futur readers) by comments about this issue for python 3 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `add_output()` function is what is called a [decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-decorator) in Python. Regardless, you can use one of the `collections` module's [ABCs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=abc#collections-abstract-base-classes) (Abstract Base Classes) to distinguish between different results from the function being wrapped. For example:

```
import collections

def add_output(fct, value):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        result = fct(*args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(result, collections.Sequence):
            return tuple(result) + (value,)
        elif result is None:
            return value
        else: # non-None and non-sequence
            return (result, value)
    return wrapped

def f1(a): return a,a+1
def f2(a): pass
g1 = add_output(f1, 42)
g2 = add_output(f2, 42)
print g1(12)            # -> (12,13,42)
print g2(12)            # -> 42
```

Depending of what sort of functions you plan on decorating, you might need to use the `collections.Iterable` ABC instead of, or in addition to, `collections.Sequence`.

Comment: Shouldn't I just test for `isinstance(result,tuple)` not to confuse (for example) a unique list output with a several output? And actually , even with tuple the problem is that it seems impossible to distinguish between a single tuple output and a set of output... I fill this is almost a philosophical issue :-)

Comment: I want an automatic wrapper, so the *sort of functions* I plan to decorate is: **any**. However it is not really critical, so I can say that decorated functions need to have "clear output", such as using: `return what_ever,` (note the `,`)

Comment: @Juh_: Generally it's preferable to do non-specific type-checking in order to be able to handle larger range of different return value types -- hence the use of ABCs instead of specific ones. However you are free to check specifically for tuple instances and, if detected, do different things depending on its length.

Comment: This is what I meant by "philosophical issue"... checking for tuple instance means that one tuple output or several of any types is **the same thing**. So for this specific exception, using specific type checking is ok...